# Using SAML Tokens in ADFS Without a Windows ID

Tags: active-directory, saml, adfs

Is it possible to use SAML tokens in ADFS without needing a Windows Id (Active Directory account)?

Comment: what is a "Functional Id"? ADFS can only authenticate users in AD. But it can also act as a "federation provider": being a chain of trust with other STSs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. ADFS can either use Active Directory accounts as identities, or use federated accounts from an upstream identity provider. You can set up any identity provider that supports SAML2 or WS-FED and connect that to ADFS. Then ADFS will treat users logging in through the upstream identity provider as real identities.

Comment: Thanks.  From a security perspective, is it possible to easily modify a SAML token in either case to hijack an identity?

Comment: You can have ADFS issue a new token with the same identity that you received from the upstream IDP. To modify the actual received token is not possible as it would void the signature (kind of the point with SAML tokens to not allow that).

Comment: How about using no identity whatsoever?  Is that possible?

Comment: A SAML token/assertion represents an identity. What do you mean with using no identity?